# What is "Windows 10 for Mobile Image - 10.0.10586.0" and can it be safely removed?

Tags: windows-10

Can't find anything on "Windows 10 for Mobile Image - 10.0.10586.0" item I found in my Programs and Features in Control Panel of fresh Windows 10 installation.

Based on the name it sounds like something that could be used by Visual Studio for emulation but since I can't find anything online and it's 2.5 GB wondering if it can be removed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the Windows 10 Mobile emulator image for Hyper-V... you can remove it unless you want to have a Win10 Mobile emulator running for some reason.

To uninstall:

**Uninstall Windows 10 for Mobile Image**

When you install the emulator, a Windows 10 for Mobile VHD image is installed, which gets its own entry in the **Programs and Features** list in the Control Panel. If you wish to uninstall the image, find **Windows 10 for Mobile Image** - in the list of installed programs, right-click on it, and choose **Uninstall**.

In the current release, you must then manually delete the VHD file for the emulator. If you installed the emulator to the default path, the VHD file is at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\Mobile\flash.vhd.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator)

Comment: Don't have Hyper-V, I think this was installed by Visual Studio 2015 to emulate Windows 10 Mobile devices for Universal Apps development...

Comment: Your comment should be an answer if you are sure.

Comment: @Moab If I was sure, I wouldn't start the sentence with "I think"...